# Laravel mailgun getting email response success but i am not able to get the mail

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, mailgun

I am working on laravel mailgun functionality, I did code for that,when i send the mail, i am not getting any error response, it says success, but i am not getting any email in gmail, can anyone please help me, how can i resolve this issue, here is my code for laravel mailgun,

```
Route::get('send_test_email', function(){
    Mail::raw('Sending emails with Mailgun and Laravel is easy!', function($message)
    {
            try {
                //$this->buildXMLHeader;
                $message->subject('Mailgun and Laravel are awesome!');
        $message->to('*****@gmail.com');
                if(count(Mail::failures()) > 0) {
                    echo "<pre>";
                    print_r(Mail::failures());
                    die;

         }
                echo "SUCCESS";exit;
              }
              catch (\Exception $e) {
                  return $e->getMessage();
              }

    });
});
```

.env code :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: What version are you using of laravel?

Comment: I assume the .env you posted is just an example and not the actual configuration you're using right?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia even still, there would need to be a configuration change there

Comment: @EstebanGarcia i am using laravel version 5.5.22

Comment: @EstebanGarcia it is actual confguration, do i need to change it ?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia can you please help me what i need to change in the .env file ?

Comment: @NikulPanchal yes, mailgun is a service that you need to sign up in order to be able to send email. Try following this tutorial: https://devdojo.com/blog/tutorials/sending-emails-with-laravel-and-mailgun

Comment: @Sohel0415 if i will change MAIL_DRIVER=smtp,  is it use mailgun ?

Comment: @EstebanGarcia yes i already signup in that, it is working for my development server, with same code, only issue in my staging server

Comment: You need to fill in the variables in the .env then.

Comment: @EstebanGarcia  .env settings are already there

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the Laravel Docs

Mailgun Driver
To use the Mailgun driver, first install Guzzle, then set the driver option in your  config/mail.php configuration file to mailgun. Next, verify that your config/services.php configuration file contains the following options:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'your-mailgun-domain',
    'secret' => 'your-mailgun-key',
],
```

The problem seems that your env config is not set up to use mailgun at all. You have added in the domain and secret to your env file

```
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=xxxxx
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxx
```

Then you can use mailables as described here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail#configuring-the-sender

Comment: laravel 5.5 does not support raw mail as far as i know

Comment: you need to generate a mailable class using php artisan make:mail {name} then use the Mail facade to send the mail

Comment: it is working in my development server, issue is in my staging server

Comment: php artisan make:mail {name}  what i need to pass in the name ?

Comment: is guzzle installed on the staging server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163405/discussion-between-devin-gray-and-nikul-panchal).